# terminal unable to generate en_IN.ISO8859-1?

Tags: locale

whenever I am trying to generate locale using

```
sudo locale-gen en_IN.ISO8859-1
```

the system is not doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`locale-gen` doesn't work that way. You only need the first language_COUNTRY:

```
$ sudo locale-gen en_IN
Generating locales...
  en_IN.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
```

Of course, you must have the locale installed:

```
$ locate en_IN
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_IN
```

Answer (score 1):

From the terminal type:

```
sudo locale-gen en_IN
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Answer (score 0):

Locales that can be generated are listed in the file `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`, and it does not include any en_IN locale with ISO-8859-1 encoding.

If you need an English locale with ISO-8859-1 encoding, you can try for instance:

```
sudo locale-gen * en_GB
```